# Feature weightage from Azure Machine Learning Deployed Web Service

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to predict from my past data which has around 20 attribute columns and a label. Out of those 20, only 4 are significant for prediction. But i also want to know that if a row falls into one of the classified categories, what other important correlated columns apart from those 4 and what are their weight. I want to get that result from my deployed web service on Azure.

Comment: Show us some of your efforts so far, and where exactly u stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use permutation feature importance module but that will give importance of the features across the sample set. Retrieving the weights on per call basis is not available in Azure ML.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. PFI is giving the importance of the features in the descending order.

Comment: i have one more doubt. For example i have applied binary classification example and my Label(PurchaseBike) can have Yes or No. If i understood PFI correctly, it is giving what features (age, country, KmTravelled, weather) are participating in predicting the value of Label column(PurchaseBike) as per their importance in descending order.  My requirement is that i wanted to get the importance of the features for those for which the predicted value is Yes.